# Alternative of Storing data except databases like mysql,sql etc

Tags: java, database, data-storage

I had completed my project Address Book in Java core, in which my data is stored in database (MySql).

I am facing a problem that when i run my program on other computer than tere is the requirement of creating the hole data base again.

So please tell me any alternative for storing my data without using any database software like mysql, sql etc.

Comment: Replies to your questions belong here. Replying to your email address defeats the purpose of SO. Also: posting your email address on a public site is a very easy way to get tons and tons of spam mail.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an in-memory database such as [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) (a.k.a [JavaDB](http://developers.sun.com/javadb/)), [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), ..

All of those can run without any additional software installation and can be made to act like just another library.

Comment: +1. but Ravi should note that the data will be lost when the application is closed.

Comment: @Bruno: not necessarily. HSQLDB can be configured to read and write its database to a file. I have no experience with the other ones, but I'm pretty sure that they can do the same.

Comment: yes, that actually makes sense. I see no reason why the db wouldn't have a feature to dump the data in memory to a file, from which it could be loaded later.

Comment: Actually the problem that i m facing is installing database and than use the same database on all pc,s
I want to make it global so that any one can use it, just like they use other Address storage software.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using an embeddable, lightweight database such as [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). Check it out.
From the features page (under the section **Suggested Uses For SQLite**):

> **Application File Format.** Rather than
>   using fopen() to write XML or some
>   proprietary format into disk files
>   used by your application, use an
>   SQLite database instead. You'll avoid
>   having to write and troubleshoot a
>   parser, your data will be more easily
>   accessible and cross-platform, and
>   your updates will be transactional.

Comment: Generally that's not a bad approach, but since the application seems to already use JDBC, an embedded JDBC-capable DB is probably the better match here. Also: from what I see SQLite isn't particularly Java-friendly. Am I wrong here?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer - I really wouldn't know, as I have never used the two together. I did however think it was worth suggesting.

Comment: there is SQLJet. 
>>>pure Java implementation of a popular SQLite database management system.
Although I haven't used it either.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of StackOverflow was so that you would not have to email around questions/answers :)

You could store data in a filesystem, memory (use serialisation etc) which are simple alternatives to DB. You can even use HSQLDB which can be run completely in memory

Comment: Hey Calm please tell me to do this all in Java.
and if there is any software which help me to do this and that is compatible with java.
please do tell me.

Answer (score 0):

If you data is not so big, you may use simple txt file and store everything in it. Then load it in memory. But this will lead to changing the way you modify/query data.

Comment: ya somewhat this type of suggestion i need.
plz tell me hw to store data in text file

Comment: If you have a single kind of data(one table in RDBMS) the simplest(by my opinion) variant is to store the date from each row from the base as CSV in the txt file. Then read it line by line. Split by separator and use it.
Hope this help )

Answer (score 0):

Database software like mysql, sql etc provides an abstraction in terms of implementation effort. If you wish to avoid using the same, you can think of having your own database like XML or flat files. XML is still a better choice as XML parsers or handlers are available. Putting your data in your customised database/flat files will not be manageable in the long run.

Why don't you explore sqlite? It is file based, means you don't need to install it separately and still you have the standard SQL to retrieve or interact with the data? I think, sqlite will be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a prevayler (.org). Faster and simpler than using a database.

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your question that you want some form of persistent storage to the local file system of the machine your application runs on. In addition to that, you need to decide on  how the data in your application is to be used, and the volume of it. Do you need a database? Are you going to be searching the data different fields? Do you need a query language? Is the data small enough to fit in to a simple data structure in memory? How resilient does it need to be? The answers to these types of questions will help lead to the correct choice of storage. It could be that all you need is a simple CSV file, XML or similar. There are a host of lightweight databases such as SQLite, Berkelely DB, JavaDB etc - but whether or not you need the power of a database is up to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

A store that I'm using a lot these days is [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org). It's a graph database and is not only easy to use but also is completely in Java and is embedded. I much prefer it to a SQL alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of the others answers about embedded databases I was working on a objects database that directly serialize java objects without the need for ORM. Its name is [Sofof](https://ramimanaf.github.io/Sofof/) and I use it in my projects. It has many features which are described in its website page.